How to cancel model binding properly?
I am trying to debug a long going issue in one of our web services.
The issue is especially when under load our instances start throwing the exception:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReadBufferState.ReadFromStreamAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean fillBuffer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsObjectAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)

Throwing the exception is actually fine, and we want it to be consistent with the timeout token we send in (it is currently set to 1 minutes from our istio load balancer) we have tracing and through that I've seen some requests take unusual amount of time (sometimes up to 10-20 minutes) even before reaching the controller (I assume it happens while model binding)
I see in the stack trace it actually calls methods with cancellationtoken parametes, but I wonder if there is a problem which makes the service don't respect the cancellation?
I've created a custom wrapper around BodyModelBinder and added below cancellation logic to it and this reduced the number of long-running requests and we return a timeout response to the client, but (due to the nature of tasks in .net) model binding still tries to finish in the background, keeps using resources and eventually fails.
We are running .net8 on k8s 1.30 and we have istio load balancer in front of this service.
I wanted to ask if there is a better/proper way to cancel the request even before reaching the controller?
Thanks in advance,
Custom cancellation code:
public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var token = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    var task = _actualModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    var delay = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token.Token);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(delay, task) == task)
    {
        // Task completed within timeout.
        // Consider that the task may have faulted or been canceled.
        // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
        token.Cancel();
        await task;
    }
    else if (bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException("Request cancelled.");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Model binding timed out.");
    }
}

Edit: I've added how I see this issue on our spans below, you can see an event after 40s which is the first thing I do in the controller (it says 'request validated') so it took 40+ seconds for this request to reach controller


TBH, It's a little bit difficult for me to get your point.. May I know more about your concerns? Maybe you are trying to find a way to cancel the request? And it's better to have an approach  worked in k8s but not in the application.

One more thing, according to .net core cancel token description, it requires CancellationTokenSource to cancel the long-running request, so that actions like clicking on the x button in the browser or navigating to another website will send a disconnection signal to your app and then cancel the request. So that I'm afraid cancel the request even before reaching the controller is unachievable.

The problem is, I have timeouts in place on load balancer - and they work fine from client's perspective, but the request continues on the server side (at least until controller, because I've added a cancellation check immediately in the controller method) I've added an image to better explain what I see on our spans.

Sorry I have no other ideas then.
